# Typescript - Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature

Tags: angular, typescript, pouchdb

I'm trying to connect to PouchDB Database and i got the error

```
Typescript Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature
```

Below is my code:-

```
var PouchDB = require("pouchdb"); 

@Injectable()
export class PouchDBService {

  private isInstantiated: boolean;
  private database: any;

  public constructor(private http: Http) {
    if(!this.isInstantiated) {

      this.database = new PouchDB("db_name"); <--error at this line
      this.isInstantiated = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[@types/pouchdb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/pouchdb) might be helpful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You might need  to pouchdb as the following:

```
import * as PouchDB from "pouchdb";
```

and then can do:

```
  this.database = new PouchDB("db_name"); //should work
```